# Can the President be impeached twice?

Tags: united-states, president, impeachment

If an impeached President (but not one removed from office) is elected for a second term, can they be impeached again during their second term if the House decides they committed new impeachable offenses? If not, is a previously impeached President more or less 'immune' to repercussions for further misconduct?

Does the boundary between terms matter, or could a President theoretically be impeached twice in the same term?

Is there any case of this happening for another office?

Comment: POTUS is one of (the?) only elected impeachable office holders, so there's no precedent.He can be impeached every day for the same thing, or for something he did before he even took office, or for wearing a tan suit. whatever half+1 of the house decides a "high crime" is.

Comment: Upvote for the [tan suit controversy](https://www.gq.com/story/barack-obama-tan-suit-anniversary) ;-)

Comment: @dandavis:  The Vice President can also be impeached, but that's it for federal elected officials.  The Constitution says that the ["President, Vice President, and all civil officers of the United States"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_in_the_United_States#Officers_subject_to_impeachment:_"civil_officers_of_the_United_States") can be impeached.  The Senate concluded in 1797 (!) that members of congress are not "civil officers" under this definition;  if a member of congress behaves badly, the "proper" remedy is expulsion.

Comment: And, of course, no Vice President has ever been impeached, so that doesn't help with precedent.

Comment: Supreme Court justices are civil officers and impeachment is the remedy for a rogue one of those.

Comment: maybe remove him actually before you dream about a sequel? ;-)

Comment: Genie, your wish is my command... It's about to happen AGAIN!!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A president can be impeached as many times as the House would like.  The House could impeach the president multiple times in the same term if they wanted to.  They could impeach on the same charges each time if they wanted to.

Impeachment isn't a criminal charge so things like double-jeopardy aren't a consideration.  The only consideration is practical and political.  If the House impeached on one set of grounds and the Senate declined to convict, it makes little sense to impeach again unless you have significantly different grounds, significantly more evidence, a significantly different Senate, or a significantly different popular sentiment that would make the old Senate reconsider their previous judgement.  Politically, impeachment already carries a significant risk of blowback which would only increase for a second or third impeachment.

I don't believe any officials have ever been impeached by the House, acquitted by the Senate, and then re-impeached by the House.

Comment: If that's the case (I hope this isn't off topic), what does impeachment actually do that can't be done by the House issuing a formal condemnation on an action? (for instance, as they recently did on Trump's withdrawal from Syria)

Comment: @Aetherfox it requires the Senate to consider the articles of impeachment, which implies the possibility of the impeached party's removal from office.  Whether that possibility is so remote as to be meaningless will be a matter of opinion, but sending the articles to the Senate will certainly have some political implications.  Whether those implications work in any given party's favor will vary, depending on many factors.

Comment: @Aetherfox - It's the difference between the House saying "That was wrong" and "We want this guy out of office".  Even if the _practical_ effect is the same either way (if the Senate won't remove), it's still the most severe step the Constitution allows for the House to take.

Comment: As a practical example, suppose the impeachment & trial come before the midterm elections, and the Senate votes not to convict on a party line vote.  Then many Senators of that party are defeated in the election, making it possible for the House to vote the same articles of impeachments, with a Senate that won't vote by party lines.

Comment: I think @jamesqf’s example should read ‘will vote by the new party lines’ ;)

Comment: I think there were multiple attempts to impeach Pres. Andrew Johnson, though I'm not sure specifically how far each "attempt" got before it failed.

Comment: @DaveInCaz He actually was impeached, just not convicted. He was impeached on 11 articles, but the Senate came 1 vote short of the 2/3 supermajority required to actually remove him.

Comment: @Jan: Possibly, but not necessarily.  In the current situation, primary elections could replace the current crop of brainwashed-by-Trump Republicans, who then go on to win the seats and vote according to evidence.  (Though I'm not holding my breath :-()

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah, I'm not holding my breath on that, either. Much more likely is that Democrats will lose the House and probably several more seats in the Senate, too. For better or for worse, it's already pretty well established at this point that Senators, like members of the House, will vote based on whether they actually think the President should be removed from office, not just on whether the evidence suggests he did what he was impeached for. Clinton had already admitted to his perjury before the Senate voted him "not guilty" of it, for example.

Comment: @reirab indeed and in that situation the response was that cheating on his wife with an employee is not grounds for impeachment... or really anything illegal or worthy of government intervention. That should have been left between him and his wife. Immoral? Heck yeah. Illegal? No, otherwise a *lot* of people should be going to jail. What they found is that he committed no crime.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck He was not impeached for cheating on his wife. He was impeached for perjury and obstruction of justice, which are crimes and which it was already well-known that he was guilty of prior to the Senate trial. The subject of the perjury just happened to be about his relations with Monica during a trial where he was being sued for sexually harassing another woman. On the day before he left office, he agreed to what was effectively a plea bargain for perjury and obstruction, under which he was fined and his law license terminated in exchange for criminal charges not being brought.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck (Incidentally, he also settled with the woman who sued him for sexual harassment and was separately fined $90,000 for civil contempt of court in relation to his perjury in that case.)

Comment: @reirab oh. I was not even aware that the person involved in the affair even lifted a finger to sue or press charges until way after the impeachment. My dates must be off on that. I’ve always heard it as an example of the government attempting to enforce moral codes that are not currently illegal and hence why it’s not a “high crime” - or a crime at all. Though technically yeah the sexual harassment *was* a crime.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Sexual harassment can be a crime in some cases, though this was a civil suit brought by Paula Jones, not a criminal one. The crimes were perjury and obstruction of justice in regards to the civil suit brought by Jones. Trying to cast the impeachment as an attempt to enforce morality was just a (largely successful) diversionary tactic used by Clinton and the Democrats. The impeachment was for perjury and obstruction of justice, not his affair with an intern.

Answer (score 1):

#### Impeachment probably isn't 'jeopardy' for Double Jeopardy purposes

The Fifth Amendment reads, in relevant part: *[N]or shall any person be subject for the same offence to be twice put in jeopardy of life or limb...*

"Of life or limb" is interpreted broadly to mean any criminal charge.  Which impeachment is not.  If convicted of a *crime*, you might suffer a wide variety of possible criminal penalties, from execution all the way down to community service or a fine.

But none of those are at issue if you are convicted in an *impeachment*.  The only two possible results of being impeached, and then convicted, are removal from office and/or being barred from holding any office in the future.  Being fired, in essence.  That's not a criminal penalty.

Practical concerns make it unlikely for impeachment to be repeated, but there's nothing stopping the House from deciding it didn't like the way the Senate tried the case, then impeaching the president again on the exact same charge.  It would be *unwise*, but not *illegal*.

Comment: It might not even be politically unwise...because it’s a political act and whether it is good or bad will be based upon whether it gets them re-elected.

Comment: I like the comparison to being fired. It's for the same reason that if your boss decides to be lenient (for whatever reason) and then gets replaced, that new boss could retroactively decide to fire you for that past action. Depending on the company that might be against the rules, but nothing practical says they can't or shouldn't do that.